# TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "list") to tuple"

Tags: python

I wrote a simple script to simulate customer lifetime value (LTV) based on average revenue per user (ARPU), margin and the number of years customers remain customers (ltvYears).  Below is my script.  It throws an error at this line "ltvYears = ltvYears + [ltv_loop]".  The error message is "TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "list") to tuple".  Can someone tell me what is causing this? I suspect the problem may stem from "ltvYears = ('f',[])" where I added the type code to eliminate another error (multiplying float by int).

I'm new to Python so there's very likely a beginner mistake in this code.

```
lowYears = 0
highYears = 20
modeYears = 3
ARPU = 65.0*12.0
MARGIN = .30
ltvYears = ('f',[])
ltv = []

def ltv(arpu, years, margin):
    return arpu * years * margin

N = 10000    
for n in range(N):
    #estimate LTV
    ltv_loop = random.triangular(lowYears, highYears, modeYears) 
    ltvYears = ltvYears + [ltv_loop]
    ltv = ltv + [ltv(ARPU, ltvYears, MARGIN)]

show = 0

if (show==1):
    #plot ltv histogram
    plt.hist(ltv,bins=10)
    plt.title("LTV Probability Density")
    plt.xlabel("")
    plt.ylabel("$")
    plt.show()
```

EDIT - Here is a screenshot of my variables.
[image]

EDIT2 ---I figured out the solution thanks to the help below.  There were three problems in total:

1. I mistakenly assigned the same name to a variable and function (+1 @autopopulated for pointing that out)
2. This line was extraneous "ltvYears = ltvYears + [ltv_loop]"
3. This line should have used used "ltv_loop" for the second argument "ltv = ltv + [calculateltv(ARPU, ltv_loop, MARGIN)]"

+1 @DonCallisto and @RikPoggi for the help that on items 2 and 3

Comment: Post the whole error message, it's clearer than splitting it out into your text.

Comment: "where I added the type code" err... what do you mean by "type code"?

Comment: @Lattyware I'm hunting for a more descriptive error message.  What I put in the question is all I'm getting from Pyscripter (which I have to use on this machine).

Comment: @MarkByers I'm referring to ltvYears = ('f',[]).  I added the 'f' to indicate that the array is to contain floats.  Before I did this I was getting an error about multiplying floats and ints.

Comment: @hughesdan: What do you mean "array"? That's a tuple, not an array. How does 'f' indicate that it contains floats? To me, it looks like it contains a string and a list.

Comment: @hughesdan: You actually didn't need to provide any additional information. You had multiple answers already by that point. And now you have lots. Your main issue is that you need to do a little more reading up on Python. Tuples and lists are not arrays, the way you are thinking of arrays.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ltvYears` is a tuple, it's defined like

```
ltvYears = ('f',[])
```

so when it comes to this line:

```
ltvYears = ltvYears + [ltv_loop]
```

Python doesn't know what to do, as your error clearly tells:

> "TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "list") to tuple"

Is not clear what the behave of that line should be, so it's hard to suggest a solution.

Maybe you just need to define ltvYears as a `list` and call the `.append` method.

---

### Edit

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10506904/typeerror-can-only-concatenate-tuple-not-list-to-tuple/#comment13584738_10506904) the OP said:

> `ltvYears = ('f',[])` I added the `'f'` to indicate that the array is to contain floats. Before I did this I was getting an error about multiplying floats and ints.

You don't need to do that. Python is not C.

Just do:

```
ltvYears = []
```

and later:

```
ltvYears.append(ltv_loop)
```

Answer (score 6):

if ltvYears is a tuple then you can concat like so:

```
ltvYears += (ltv_loop,)
```

Answer (score 2):

From your code

```
ltvYears = ltvYears + [ltv_loop]
```

`ltvYears` is a tuple, and that's why you get that error.

That's because you can't append a `list` to a tuple. Maybe you have to change the type of `ltvYears` making it a list

Comment: Is more than probably, it's exactly defined like a tuple: `ltvYears = ('f',[])`

Comment: @RikPoggi : by reading again the question, i've noticed that and i update just a uSecond before you told me that :)

Answer (score 2):

(This is a different problem to the one you're asking about, see @Rik's answer for that, but you've also got this problem)

You've defined a function with the same name as a variable:

```
...
ltv = []

def ltv(arpu, years, margin):
    return arpu * years * margin
...
```

This will replace your list variable with the function object, which of course you can't append to, so this line will fail: `ltv = ltv + [ltv(ARPU, ltvYears, MARGIN)]`.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually as simple as the error message states:  You are not allowed to concatenate lists and tuples.

`ltvYears` is a tuple. `[ltv_loop]` is a list.